# why do not we use sqoop eval in production environment, what is the disadvantage by using sqoop eval?

Tags: eval, sqoop

using sqoop eval we can evaluate the connection with the database. but after that why do not we use for query propose in production environment, what's it's import in production.

sqoop eval \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db \
    --username retail_dba \
    --password cloudera \
    --query "SELECT * FROM orders LIMIT 10"

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop Eval is only used to print the output of the query to the console. It is not used to import data from RDBMS to Hdfs. So "Sqoop eval" is a functionality where we get output only on console. It does not provide functionality to move data to hdfs.

Whereas, Sqoop import is actually used to import the data to hdfs.